# Adding Text onto a Rect

Tags: python, pygame

So I have defined a function Meteor and set up the dimensions and where it will appear on the screen.

```
def Meteor(Meteorx, Meteory, Meteorw, Meteorh, colour):
    pygame.draw.rect(Screen, colour, [Meteorx,Meteory, Meteorw, Meteorh])
```

but I wanted to add text to it but I can't work out how to blit it onto a rectangle (note: I have tried to play around with font.render etc). Am I going the right way about this or is there a simpler way than putting it onto the rect surface.

Source code https://github.com/WamblyTK/Word-Blaster/blob/master/Full%20Draft%20%231

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need a [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html), which can be created by [`pygame.font.SysFont()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont) or `pygame.font.Font`. e.g.:

```py
import pygame.font

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
```

With the font object a text can be rendered by [`.render()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render). The result is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object.
If you want you can scale the surface to a certain size, by [`pygame.transform.smoothscale`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/transform.html#pygame.transform.smoothscale).
Finally the text can be drawn to the surface by [`blit`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit). e.g.:

```py
def Meteor(Meteorx, Meteory, Meteorw, Meteorh, colour):
    text = font.render('test text', False, colour)
    text = pygame.transform.smoothscale(text.convert(), (Meteorw, Meteorh))
    Screen.blit(text, (Meteorx, Meteory))
```

---

As mentioned in the comment below it is easier to use [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render). e.g.:

```py
import pygame.freetype

font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Times New Roman', 30)
```

```py
def Meteor(Meteorx, Meteory, Meteorw, Meteorh, colour):
    font.render_to(Screen, (Meteorx, Meteory), 'test text', colour, size=Meteorw)
```

Comment: Note there's also the [`pygame.freetype` module](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html), which is an improved replacement for the `pygame.font` module.

Comment: I provided both solutions, using [`pygame.font`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html) or [`pygame.freetype`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html)